# Deploy Google App Engine managed VM to location in Europe

Tags: google-app-engine

By default, managed VMs are deployed to the US.

I've searched the google documentation for appengine and could not found how to set the location where the managed VM will be created.

How to configure the app.yaml to deploy a managed VM to Europe?

Comment: The docs say that managed vm doesnt work in europe: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, managed VMs are not available in the European region. They are US only.  Even if you create your application in the console under the 'EU', when you try to deploy your VM to it, you'll get the message `Managed VMs can not be hosted in Europe.`.

Maybe Google will update support for VMs in the EU in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself but to host normal apps in EU you need to create the application in EU. Create the app using this [console](https://appengine.google.com/). Under 'Location Options' select EU. Then when you push your managed vm use that project.